# Sphinx Results Take Huge Time To Show (Slow Index)

Tags: performance-testing, sphinx

I'm new to Sphinx, i have simple table tbl_urls with two columns (domain_id,url)
i created my index as below to get domain id and number of urls for any giving keyword

```
source src2
{
  type                  = mysql
  sql_host              = 0.0.0.0
  sql_user              = spnx
  sql_pass              = 123
  sql_db                = db_spnx
  sql_port              = 3306 # optional, default is 3306
  sql_query             = select id,domain_id,url from tbl_domain_urls
  sql_attr_uint         = domain_id
  sql_field_string      = url
}
index url_tbl
{
    source   = src2
    path     =/var/lib/sphinx/data/url_tbl
}
indexer
{
    mem_limit               = 2047M
}
searchd
{
    listen                  = 0.0.0.0:9312
    listen                  = 0.0.0.0:9306:mysql41
    listen                  = /home/charlie/sphinx-3.4.1/bin/searchd.sock:sphinx
    log                     = /var/log/sphinx/sphinx.log
    query_log               = /var/log/sphinx/query.log
    read_timeout            = 5
    max_children            = 30
    pid_file                = /var/run/sphinx/sphinx.pid
    max_filter_values       = 20000
    seamless_rotate         = 1
    preopen_indexes         = 0
    unlink_old              = 1
    workers                 = threads # for RT indexes to work
    binlog_path             = /var/lib/sphinx/data
    max_batch_queries       = 128
}
```

problem is the time taken to show results is over one min

```
SELECT domain_id,count(*) as url_counter
FROM ul_tbl WHERE MATCH('games')
group by domain_id limit 1000000 OPTION max_matches=1000000;show meta;

+-----------+-------+
| domain_id | url   |
+-----------+-------+
|      9900 |   444 |
|     41309 |    48 |
|     62308 |   491 |
|     85798 |   401 |
|       595 |  4851 |


13545 rows in set (3 min 22.56 sec)

+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| total         | 13545  |
| total_found   | 13545  |
| time          | 1.406  |
| keyword[0]    | games  |
| docs[0]       | 456667 |
| hits[0]       | 514718 |
+---------------+--------+
```

table tbl_domain_urls 100,821,614 rows
dedicated server HP Proliant 2xL5420 16GB RAM 2x1TB HDD

**I need your support to optimize my QUERY or config settings**, i need the results in the lowest time possible, i really appreciate any new idea to test

Note:
I tried distributed index to use multiple core for processing without any noticable results

Comment: You are setting a huge limit/max_matches. Means sphinx will have to allocate memory for all thous results. Do you really need such million results? Honestly for such huge resultsets, won't be able to squeeze much of a performance boost

Comment: @barryhunter i dont use all of the results, i take these domain ids and do inner join with normal mysql tables to filter out down to around 200 result, are you suggesting to build all joins and query it self in sphinx ?

Comment: Absolutely should denormalise, and do the full filtering in sphinx. With attributes can basically store full copy of data so can get the final resultset from sphinx